# Fedora 25 (as guest) won't start after adding a CPU on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, fedora

I'm running Fedora 25 (Linux 4.10.10) on top of VirtualBox 5.1 (Windows guest).
The VM is configured with 4GB of RAM and 1 CPU and it's working quite well.
If I add a CPU to the VM, Fedora won't start anymore.
I get the grub menu, but after selecting the boot entry, all I see is a black screen with a blinking cursor at the top.
Any idea?

Comment: Have you enabled *I/O APIC* in machine's settings? Was it enabled previously?

Comment: Yes it's enabled and it was before (at time of installation).

Comment: If you edit the grub entry by deleting "quiet" and "rhgb", do you see any clues while it tries to boot?